# Using Python to Import CSV to a MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql

I can not execute a Python file to import CSV file to MySQL table.

```
import csv
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
 host='localhost',
 user='root',
 passwd='',
 database='ricoh_oms'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(open("slv_internal.csv"))
for row in csv_data:
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO slv_internal (GID, FullName, CostCenter) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")

mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print("Done")
```

I am newbie and dont understand the meaning of marker %s in the error. Thansk for your help. The error is:

**Error:**

> "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s)' at
>   line 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to Execute Parameterized Query

Example:

```
insert_stmt = (
  "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date) "
  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
data = (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', datetime.date(2012, 3, 23))
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

in code you are missing parameters:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO slv_internal (GID, FullName, CostCenter) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", ("value1","value2","value3"))
```

some documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Thanks. I execute your code and now the error is mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'value1' for key 'PRIMARY'